# I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu using Ajax but the list isnt loading

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu using ajax but its not loading the list.
My dropdownlist is loaded from my controller for both the categories and the brands. But I cant seem to get the brands dropdownlist load dynamically on selection from the category dropdownlist. I don't know where I am getting it wrong.

My Blade file

```
@extends('layout.frontLayouts.design')
@section('content')

                <!-- Start Login Register Content -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <!-- Start Single Content -->
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="registerForm" name="registerForm" action="{{ url('/post-advert') }}" method="POST" novalidate>{{ csrf_field() }}
                                <label for="cat">Categories</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
                                    <?php echo $categories_drop_down; ?>
                                </select>
                                <label for="brand">Select Brand</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="brand_id" id="brand_id">
                                    <?php echo $brands_drop_down; ?>
                                </select>
                                <label for="title">Product Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Product Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Title'">
                                <label for="cond">Product Condition</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="product_condition" name="product_condition">
                                    <option value="">Select Product Condition</option>
                                    <option value="new">New</option>
                                    <option value="old">Old</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="Product Description">Product Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" rows="10" placeholder="Description" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Description'"></textarea>
                                <label for="state">State</label>
                                <select class="form-control" onchange="toggleLGA(this);" name="state" id="state">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">- Select State -</option>
                                    <option value="Abia">Abia</option>
                                    <option value="Adamawa">Adamawa</option>
                                    <option value="Akwa Ibom">Akwa Ibom</option>
                                    <option value="Anambra">Anambra</option>
                                    <option value="Bauchi">Bauchi</option>
                                    <option value="Bayelsa">Bayelsa</option>
                                    <option value="Benue">Benue</option>
                                    <option value="Borno">Borno</option>
                                    <option value="Cross River">Cross River</option>
                                    <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
                                    <option value="Ebonyi">Ebonyi</option>
                                    <option value="Edo">Edo</option>
                                    <option value="Ekiti">Ekiti</option>
                                    <option value="Enugu">Enugu</option>
                                    <option value="FCT">FCT</option>
                                    <option value="Gombe">Gombe</option>
                                    <option value="Imo">Imo</option>
                                    <option value="Jigawa">Jigawa</option>
                                    <option value="Kaduna">Kaduna</option>
                                    <option value="Kano">Kano</option>
                                    <option value="Katsina">Katsina</option>
                                    <option value="Kebbi">Kebbi</option>
                                    <option value="Kogi">Kogi</option>
                                    <option value="Kwara">Kwara</option>
                                    <option value="Lagos">Lagos</option>
                                    <option value="Nasarawa">Nasarawa</option>
                                    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                                    <option value="Ogun">Ogun</option>
                                    <option value="Ondo">Ondo</option>
                                    <option value="Osun">Osun</option>
                                    <option value="Oyo">Oyo</option>
                                    <option value="Plateau">Plateau</option>
                                    <option value="Rivers">Rivers</option>
                                    <option value="Sokoto">Sokoto</option>
                                    <option value="Taraba">Taraba</option>
                                    <option value="Yobe">Yobe</option>
                                    <option value="Zamfara">Zamafara</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="lg">Location</label>
                                <select name="lga" id="lga" class="form-control select-lga">
                                </select>
                                <label for="price">Price</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Price" >
                                <label for="ph">WhatsApp Phone Number</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+2347000000000">
                                <label for="Neg">Negotiable</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="neg" id="neg" value="1"><br>
                                <label for="stat">Enable Advert</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="1">
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Post Advert</button>
                            </form>
                            <!-- End Single Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Login Register Content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Login Register Area -->

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        
    <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#category_id').on('change', function () {
                let id = $(this).val();
                $('#brand_id').empty();
                $('#brand_id').append(`<option value="0" disabled selected>Processing...</option>`);
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getbrands/' + id,
                success: function (response) {
                var response = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response);   
                $('#brand_id').empty();
                $('#brand_id').append(`<option value="0" disabled selected>Select Brands*</option>`);
                response.forEach(element => {
                    $('#brand_id').append(`<option value="${element['id']}">${element['name']}</option>`);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

@endsection
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use App\Brands;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use DB;

    public function advert(Request $request) {

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_first_name = Auth::user()->first_name;
        $user_last_name = Auth::user()->last_name;
        $user_email = Auth::user()->email;
        $userDetails = User::find($user_id);
        $profile = Auth::user()->mobile;
        if( is_null($profile) ){
            return redirect()->action('UsersController@account')->with('flash_message_success','Please update your profile before you can continue...');
       }

        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all();
            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
            
            $data = request()->validate([
                'category_id' => 'required',
                'brand_id' => 'required',
                'product_name' => 'required',
                'product_condition' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required',
                'state' => 'required',
                'lga' => 'required',
                'price' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required|regex:/(234)[0-9]{10}/',
                'neg' => 'nullable',
                'status' => 'nullable'
            
            ],
            [
                'category_id.required' => 'Category not specified!',
                'brand_id.required' => 'Brand not specified!',
                'product_name.required' => 'Product Name cannot be empty!',
                'product_condition.required' => 'Please specify Product Condition!',
                'description.required' => 'Product Description cannnot be empty!',
                'state.required' => 'State not specified!',
                'lga.required' => 'Specify Product Location!',
                'phone.required' => 'WhatsApp Phone Number not found',
                'phone.regex' => 'Please check if your whatsapp phone number is correct! (2347000000000)',
                'price.required' => 'Product Price cannot be empty!',
                'image.required' => 'Product Image not found!'
            ]);

            $product = new Product;
            $product->user_id = $user_id;
            $product->user_first_name = $user_first_name;
            $product->user_last_name = $user_last_name;
            $product->user_email = $user_email;
            $product->category_id = $data['category_id'];
            $product->brand_id = $data['brand_id'];
            $product->product_name = $data['product_name'];
            $product->product_condition = $data['product_condition'];
            $product->description = $data['description'];
            $product->state = $data['state'];
            $product->lga = $data['lga'];
            $product->price = $data['price'];
            $product->phone = $data['phone'];

            $product->neg = $data['neg'];
            $product->status = $data['status'];
            $product->save();
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product has been added successfully!');
        }

        $categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $categories_drop_down = "<option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>";
        foreach($categories as $cat){
            $categories_drop_down .= "<option value='".$cat->id."'>".$cat->name."</option>";
            $sub_categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => $cat->id])->get();
            foreach($sub_categories as $sub_cat){
                $categories_drop_down .= "<option value='".$sub_cat->id."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;".$sub_cat->name."</option>";    
            }   
        }

        $brands = Brands::get();
        $brands_drop_down = "<option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>";
        foreach($brands as $brand){
            $brands_drop_down .= "<option value='".$brand->id."'>".$brand->name."</option>";
        }

        return view('pages.advert')->with(compact('categories', 'categories_drop_down', 'brands_drop_down'));
    }

    public function GetBrands($id){
        echo json_encode(DB::table('brands')->where('category_id', $id)->get());
    }
}
```

My Routes

```
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/post-advert', 'frontController@advert');
    Route::get('getbrands/{id}', 'frontController@GetBrands');
```

Comment: Did you know, that instead of `<?php echo $categories_drop_down; ?>` you can simply do `{{ $categories_drop_down }}` in blade?

Comment: Do you have any error messages? What does your `console.log(response);` output?

Comment: Its not showing any error

Comment: What does your `console.log(response);` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your ajax method `GetBrands` specifically this line:

`echo json_encode(DB::table('brands')->where('category_id', $id)->get());`

you should use `return` instead of `echo` it should be like this:

`return json_encode(DB::table('brands')->where('category_id', $id)->get());`

and in laravel you can easily replace this :

```
 <?php echo $categories_drop_down; ?>
```

with this :

```
{{ $categories_drop_down }}
```